# How to design an android app using web service's APIs with RoboSpice?

Tags: android, api, robospice

I'm writing an android app for a web service like Twitter using its APIs, and I've chosen RoboSpice to make it easier to perform network requests and deal with cache. But I don't know how can I combine the APIs with RoboSpice.

In RoboSpice's [starter guide](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Starter-guide), they used GitHub's follower API as an example, but they wrote the URL right inside the `loadDataFromNetwork` method, does this mean they want to do all the works like this to all the APIs there? At the same time they transfer the JSON to POJO, but they didn't show what to do with the POJO next.

I'd like to know if there is any best practice with using web APIs in android app.